# On table scroll listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to find out event of scrolling tables. 
I can get the left param, for example, using:

```
$("#scrollTable").offset().left
```

But I can't add the listener of its changing.
Everything I want is to monitor the changing of left scroll parameter of table and apply it to another DOM element (that is not a problem).

HTML example of my table:

```
    <div class="scrollTableOuter">
        <div id="scrollTableInner" class="scrollTableInner">
<table id="scrollTable" class="persist-area">
    <thead>
        <tr class="persist-header">
        <th style="height: 80px;">Name</th>
        <td style="width: 80px;">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 80px;">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input class="arrow-change" style="width: 35px; text-align: right;" autocomplete="off" min="0" name="AwardEvent[2][3][value]" id="AwardEvent_2_3_value" type="number" value="1">
        </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div></div>
```

Comment: How are you scrolling a table? Can you post your HTML.

Comment: Try to `console it` by using, `console.log($("#scrollTable").offset());`. And check what you get in it.

Comment: @Rohan, i have this: Object {top: 225, left: 160}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind a listener to the `'scroll'` event, as [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) point out.

```
$('#target').on('scroll', function() {
    // your code
});
```

obviously, `#target` should be a selector for the element that houses the scrollbars, possibly `document` or a div you have on `overflow`

Comment: @AxelPAL which is why I asked to see your HTML ;)

Comment: doesn't work for tables? HTML doesnt even have scrolling tables... you should have a container div handeling the scrolling (with `overflow: scroll`) and regiter a listener on that div

Comment: @Nicky, yes, that was the problem. I have divs for that and just forgotten about it. Thank you!

Comment: i have this function work for non-dynamically created table, how should i change it to handle dynamically created table?
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.main-table tbody').scroll(function(e) {
    $('.main-table thead').css("left", -$(".main-table tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('.main-table thead tr th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $(".main-table tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
    $('.main-table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $(".main-table tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
  });
});