# How Can I Load Data On Scroll In Html using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a HTML Dynamic Table

```
<div class="clearfix reportWrapper" >
    <div class="reportTable">
        <table class="table table-bordered footerBGColor">
            <thead fix-head class="headerTable">
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in vm.contractBillingReportList[0]" >{{header}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.contractBillingReportList track by $index">
                    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in item" ng-class="vm.getWidthValue(key, value, item)">
                                    {{value}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

the data in  contractBillingReportList comes from angular Function

```
vm.OpenBManageContractBillingReport = function () {
    vm.showTable = true;
    vm.Search.BillingReportType= "DetailReport",
    reportService.GetContractBillingList(vm.Search).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        vm.contractBillingReportList = response;
    }, function (err) {

    });
};
```

Now the Problem is According to the search criteria The Data is Loaded and sometimes the number of data is huge 5000-10000. In that case all the Data is Loaded on Angular function `contractBillingReportList` but binding to the html table (in case of huge data) takes lot of time and entire page get hang. How can i apply Load On Demand such that at first only 1000 data is displayed and while scrolling more data is loaded (example:- like news feed on facebook).

Comment: Can't you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add an event listener [`on-scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll) to the body of the table, there are different ways of doing it and check if you are at the bottom, depends if you want to use jquery or not, and the layout of your view [Example with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990738/on-table-scroll-listener), [Other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954799/angularjs-how-to-trigger-event-when-scroll-reaches-to-the-bottom-of-the-scroll)

After you bind to this event, you need to update your service, you shouldn't request 10000 items every single time, you should pass some parameter on your web service that enables pagination and the amount you want to receive every time, for example, if you want to show 100 items at the time, you have to request the first page of the query of 100 items, on scroll you do the request again but increasing the page name by 1, then you get the next 100 items, and so on, however remember to use [one time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) on the individual items on your template otherwise eventually you are going to have performance issues:

```
vm.OpenBManageContractBillingReport = function () {
  vm.currentPage = !vm.currentPage ? 0 : vm.currentPage + 1;
  reportService.GetContractBillingList({
    searchText: vm.Search,
    page: vm.currentPage,
    resultLimit: 100,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        vm.contractBillingReportList = response;
    }, function (err) {

    });
};
```

And again, if you Web service API does not support pagination, they you have to do some very nasty solution, like getting all the results and filter in memory those results, and then push that chunk into the `vm.contractBillingReportList` variable... Not recommended